# How to make camera zoom animation based on position

Tags: animation, camera

I want to create an animation in blender where the camera zooms in to an object. I've seen [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23783/zoom-with-camera-in-an-animation) post and what I'd like to do is animate the camera position like user7952 said. But I'm not sure how to do that. Should I insert keyframe while in layout mode or should I go to animation mode and do it there?  And how do I insert keyframes? I'm a beginner at blender. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's Layout or Animation node. These are just different default windows setups which might be more useful to specific tasks. You can always rearrange windows to your taste. To insert a keyframe, with an object selected in 3D viewport, hit "I" for insert and get a menu what you want to keyframe. or hit "I" over a value field to create a keyframe. That sets keyframes for the active object at the current frame. But not even knowing how to set a keyframe sounds to me like you should do some basic animation tutorials first because making animations can be quite complex.

Comment: i would recommend you watch the free beginner tutorials for Blender: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/#get-started.